# Rocket Jumping in Overwatch

Tags: overwatch

I have a couple questions regarding rocket jumping in Overwatch

- How do you do a successful rocket jump? What are the inputs and their order?
- Do different characters have different ways to optimize their distance/height with rocket jumping? If so, what are the order of inputs?

Comment: It's a little unclear from the question as to what a good answer would be - are you asking for Zarya, or for how rocket jumping works in general. It might be better to have the question 'Who can "Rocket Jump" in Overwatch?', and to ask in the body the technique for doing it with each character. This lends itself to a complete answer across all heroes.

Comment: @Samthere They ask how it works and are giving Zarya as an example of a hero they probably use often than has the ability at their disposal, and thus would like to see an answer that contains that example.

Comment: @ИвоНедев I understand the intent of the question, and I don't mean to suggest by "unclear" that it should be closed. I just meant to suggest an optional edit to the asker that might invite more detailed, high quality answers. :)

Comment: @Samthere I see what you mean and I will try to edit it for better questions. Looking at ИвоНедев answer, it seems characters have different ways to maximize their jump - which I was totally unaware of - so I will try to edit it to make a better questions for better answers

Comment: @Samthere I just edited the question, is this more of what you mean?

Comment: @bmarkham Yes, I think that's good.

Comment: Related - http://www.nerfnow.com/comic/1841

Comment: Pharah has a relevant voice line; I won't quote it to avoid the spoiler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It kind of comes to you naturally when you try it a couple of times. Besides Zarya, Soldier and Bastion (in Tank configuration) are also quite good at rocket jumping.

The order is: 
Look down -> Jump ->(Immediately after the jump, but a bit of distance off the ground) Alternative fire.

It also works for Phara, but not only with her rockets (though they work just fine and give plenty of upwards lift). I'm a Phara main and hardly ever see this used:
Make sure the sky is clear, and there is nothing to stop you as you go really high really fast -> Look down -> and use both her abilities at the same exact time.

This boosts you really really high in the sky, I've been called hacker and glitcher once or twice because of this.

Comment: If you spin and don't look directly down, you can cover some awesome distance with this combo. I usually do it to gap close or rush back to the team if I over extend and die. I really gotta work on my overextending :P

Comment: I've edited the question if you'd like to edit your answer as well

Comment: @bmarkham I'm good thanks, the answer is still quite valid and correct in my opinion.

Comment: I'd say so too! Never knew the Phara trick. Must try it myself when next time I play. It makes me wanna try out some Phara

Comment: Are you sure Bastion has a corresponding alt-attack or any other means to propel itself into the air?

Comment: @npst He does in tank mode

Comment: @npst Only while he's ulting.

Comment: Should Junkrat be included here? I know its not a "rocket" but it is similar enough.

Comment: @Matt Not similar enough actually, his is more an ability like Pharah's and Genji's movement abilities.

Comment: @DCShannon  I believe that would be both of her abilities, the rocket jump and concussive blast. So it would be the shoulder buttons L1 + R1 (LB + RB).

Comment: @DCShannon Sorry, edited on both points.